# Where is the location of Odoo 15 log file on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, logging, odoo

I can't find the Odoo log file for Odoo 15 on Ubuntu 20.04. There is no Odoo folder or file related to logging at `/var/log`

```
root@admin:/var/log# ls -l
total 4648
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root              11701 Nov 19 03:50 alternatives.log
drwxr-x---  2 root        adm                4096 Nov 22 00:00 apache2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root        root               4096 Nov 19 07:16 apt
-rw-r-----  1 syslog      adm              855529 Nov 22 03:28 auth.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog      adm             1181873 Nov 21 00:00 auth.log.1
-rw-rw----  1 root        utmp            2396545 Nov 22 03:28 btmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root        adm                   0 May 25 19:28 dmesg
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root             135962 Nov 19 07:17 dpkg.log
drwxr-s---  2 Debian-exim adm                4096 Nov 22 00:10 exim4
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root               3520 Nov 19 02:55 faillog
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root               1702 Nov 19 07:17 fontconfig.log
drwxr-sr-x+ 3 root        systemd-journal    4096 May 25 19:28 journal
-rw-rw-r--  1 root        utmp              32120 Nov 22 03:28 lastlog
drwxrwxr-t  2 root        postgres           4096 Nov 21 00:00 postgresql
drwx------  2 root        root               4096 May 25 02:07 private
-rw-r-----  1 syslog      adm                4205 Nov 22 03:25 syslog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog      adm               19414 Nov 22 00:00 syslog.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog      adm                7848 Nov 21 00:00 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog      adm               10919 Nov 20 00:00 syslog.3.gz
drwxr-xr-x  2 root        root               4096 Aug  9 14:08 sysstat
-rw-rw-r--  1 root        utmp              46848 Nov 22 03:28 wtmp
```

Comment: Depends on the installation or even more on the odoo config. That one is usually on `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf` and you can define how and where to log.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. So the Odoo default setting not generated log file

Comment: That is right. I will write a little answer.

Comment: Ok good, I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [current documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/misc/other/cmdline.html#logging) says following:

> Logging
> By default, Odoo displays all logging of level info except for workflow logging (warning only), **and log output is sent to stdout**. Various options are available to redirect logging to other destinations and to customize the amount of logging output.

You can change it by starting Odoo with following parameter or defining this parameter in Odoo's config file.

> `--logfile <file>`
>
> sends logging output to the specified file instead of stdout. On Unix, the file can be managed by external log rotation programs and will automatically be reopened when replaced